LLM SSE bug using React, Postgres SQL, Python
We have an. LLM chat engine in the back-end serving results with SSE to react app. Back-end is developed under Python, Fastapi. We get this error that we don’t really understand. Can anyone help us please ?


"GET /api/conversation/5bcfc2dd-719d-45ce-8f73-e01fd4454c33/message?user_message=Whats%20the%20PPA%20price%20?&user_id=0bafa244-05ba-4599-881b-b9a096e853af HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
using gpt-model gpt-3.5-turbo-0613
Getting tools...
Chat engine...
Added user message to memory: Remember - if I have asked a relevant financial question, use your tools.

Whats the PPA price ?
event_type CBEventType.AGENT_STEP

event_type CBEventType.LLM

Exception terminating connection \<AdaptedConnection \<asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x184678ac0\>\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1306, in \_checkout
result = pool.\_dialect.\_do_ping_w_event(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 709, in _do_ping_w_event
return self.do_ping(dbapi_connection)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 1142, in do_ping
dbapi_connection.ping()
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 816, in ping
\_ = self.await_(self.\_async_ping())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 130, in await_only
return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore\[no-any-return\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 195, in greenlet_spawn
value = await result
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 825, in \_async_ping
await tr.start()
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/transaction.py", line 138, in start
await self.\_connection.execute(query)
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 317, in execute
return await self.\_protocol.query(query, timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 338, in query
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/futures.py", line 287, in __await__
yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 349, in \__wakeup
future.result()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/futures.py", line 198, in result
raise exc
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError: Cancelled by cancel scope 184dabb90

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 377, in \_close_connection
self._dialect.do_terminate(connection)
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 1109, in do_terminate
dbapi_connection.terminate()
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 892, in terminate
self.await_(self.\_connection.close(timeout=2))
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 130, in await_only
return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore\[no-any-return\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 195, in greenlet_spawn
value = await result
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1333, in close
await self.\_protocol.close(timeout)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 349, in \__wakeup
future.result()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/futures.py", line 198, in result
raise exc
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError: Cancelled by cancel scope 184dabb90
event_type CBEventType.LLM\`

Some other error we get :
` Exception in callback Task.task_wakeup(<Future finished result=None>) handle: <Handle Task.task_wakeup(<Future finished result=None>)> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 84, in _run     self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args) RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Server.serve() running at /Users/saadlachhab/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-app-backend-WThbfXrG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py:81> wait_for=<Future finished result=None> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py:181]> while another task <Task cancelling name='Task-13' coro=<handle_chat_message() running at /Users/saadlachhab/Downloads/financeapp-back/app/chat/messaging.py:214>> is being executed.


We have the code :

@router.get("/{conversation_id}/message")
async def message_conversation(
request: Request,
conversation_id: UUID,
user_message: str,
user_id: UUID,
db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
) -\> EventSourceResponse:
async with db.begin():
conversation = await crud.fetch_conversation_with_messages(
db, conversation_id, user_id
)
if conversation is None:
raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Conversation not found")

        if (
            conversation.messages
        ):  # Assuming `conversation.messages` checks if there are any messages
            # Process as usual if not the first message
            pass
        else:
            # This is the first message, generate a conversation title
            title = await generate_conversation_title(
                user_message
            )  # Implement this function to use GPT-3.5
            # udpate conversation title in sql with title
            await crud.update_conversation_title(db, conversation_id, title)
    
        user_message = Message(
            created_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            updated_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            conversation_id=conversation_id,
            content=user_message,
            role=MessageRoleEnum.user,
            status=MessageStatusEnum.SUCCESS,
        )
    
        send_chan, recv_chan = anyio.create_memory_object_stream(100)
    
        async def event_publisher():
            async with send_chan, recv_chan:
                task = asyncio.create_task(
                    handle_chat_message(conversation, user_message, send_chan)
                )
                message_id = str(uuid4())
                message = Message(
                    id=message_id,
                    conversation_id=conversation_id,
                    content="",
                    role=MessageRoleEnum.assistant,
                    status=MessageStatusEnum.PENDING,
                    sub_processes=[],
                )
                final_status = MessageStatusEnum.ERROR
                event_id_to_sub_process = OrderedDict()
                try:
                    async for message_obj in recv_chan:
                        if isinstance(message_obj, StreamedMessage):
                            message.content = message_obj.content
                        elif isinstance(message_obj, StreamedMessageSubProcess):
                            status = (
                                MessageSubProcessStatusEnum.FINISHED
                                if message_obj.has_ended
                                else MessageSubProcessStatusEnum.PENDING
                            )
                            if message_obj.event_id in event_id_to_sub_process:
                                created_at = event_id_to_sub_process[
                                    message_obj.event_id
                                ].created_at
                            else:
                                created_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                            sub_process = MessageSubProcess(
                                # NOTE: By setting the created_at to the current time, we are
                                # no longer able to use the created_at field to determine the
                                # time at which the subprocess was inserted into the database.
                                created_at=created_at,
                                message_id=message_id,
                                source=message_obj.source,
                                metadata_map=message_obj.metadata_map,
                                status=status,
                            )
                            event_id_to_sub_process[message_obj.event_id] = sub_process
    
                            message.sub_processes = list(
                                event_id_to_sub_process.values()
                            )
                        else:
                            logger.error(
                                f"Unknown message object type: {type(message_obj)}"
                            )
                            continue
                        yield schema.Message.from_orm(message).json()
                    await task
                    if task.exception():
                        raise ValueError(
                            "handle_chat_message task failed"
                        ) from task.exception()
                    final_status = MessageStatusEnum.SUCCESS
                except asyncio.CancelledError:
                    # Handle cancellation, possibly cleaning up or logging
                    pass
                except:
                    logger.error("Error in message publisher", exc_info=True)
                    final_status = MessageStatusEnum.ERROR
                    await db.rollback()  # Rollback in case of any exception
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal server error")
                message.status = final_status
                db.add(user_message)
                db.add(message)
                await db.commit()
                final_message = await crud.fetch_message_with_sub_processes(
                    db, message_id
                )
                yield final_message.json()
    
        return EventSourceResponse(event_publisher())


class StreamedMessage(BaseModel):
content: str

class StreamedMessageSubProcess(BaseModel):
source: MessageSubProcessSourceEnum
has_ended: bool
event_id: str
metadata_map: Optional\[SubProcessMetadataMap\]

class SubQuestionAnswerPairStream(BaseModel):
question: str
answer: str
sources: Optional\[List\[NodeWithScore\]\] = None

class ChatCallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
def __init__(
self,
send_chan: MemoryObjectSendStream,
):
"""Initialize the base callback handler."""
\# ignored_events = \[CBEventType.CHUNKING, CBEventType.NODE_PARSING\]
\# super().__init__(ignored_events, ignored_events)
self.ignored_events = \[
CBEventType.CHUNKING,
CBEventType.NODE_PARSING,
\]  # Define ignored events
super().__init__(self.ignored_events, self.ignored_events)
self.\_send_chan = send_chan

    def on_event_start(
        self,
        event_type: CBEventType,
        payload: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        event_id: str = "",
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> str:
        """Create the MessageSubProcess row for the event that started."""
        asyncio.create_task(
            self.async_on_event(
                event_type, payload, event_id, is_start_event=True, **kwargs
            )
        )
    
    def on_event_end(
        self,
        event_type: CBEventType,
        payload: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        event_id: str = "",
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        """Create the MessageSubProcess row for the event that completed."""
        asyncio.create_task(
            self.async_on_event(
                event_type, payload, event_id, is_start_event=False, **kwargs
            )
        )
    
    def get_metadata_from_event(
        self,
        event_type: CBEventType,
        payload: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        is_start_event: bool = False,
    ) -> SubProcessMetadataMap:
        metadata_map = {}
        if (
            event_type == CBEventType.SUB_QUESTION
            and EventPayload.SUB_QUESTION in payload
        ):
            sub_q: SubQuestionAnswerPair = payload[EventPayload.SUB_QUESTION]
            metadata_map[SubProcessMetadataKeysEnum.SUB_QUESTION.value] = (
                schema.QuestionAnswerPair.from_sub_question_answer_pair(sub_q).dict()
            )
        elif payload and EventPayload.RESPONSE in payload:
            pay = payload[EventPayload.RESPONSE]
            if hasattr(pay, "metadata"):
                if "sub_qa" in pay.metadata:
                    sub_qa_content = pay.metadata["sub_qa"]
                    first_question, first_response = sub_qa_content[0]
                    # print(f"...... question = {first_question}")
                    # print(f"...... answer = {first_response.response}")
                    # Corrected line: Assuming 'source_nodes' is an attribute of 'first_response'
                    # print(f"...... sources = {first_response.source_nodes}")
    
                    sub_q = {
                        "question": first_question,
                        "answer": first_response.response,
                        "sources": first_response.source_nodes,
                    }
    
                    sub_q_object = SubQuestionAnswerPairStream(**sub_q)
    
                    metadata_map[SubProcessMetadataKeysEnum.SUB_QUESTION.value] = (
                        schema.QuestionAnswerPair.from_sub_question_answer_pair(
                            sub_q_object
                        ).dict()
                    )
    
        #     metadata_map
        return metadata_map
    
    async def async_on_event(
        self,
        event_type: CBEventType,
        payload: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        event_id: str = "",
        is_start_event: bool = False,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
    
        if event_type in self.ignored_events:
            logger.debug(
                f"Ignoring event {event_type} as it is in the list of ignored events."
            )
            return
    
        metadata_map = self.get_metadata_from_event(
            event_type, payload=payload, is_start_event=is_start_event
        )
        metadata_map = metadata_map or None
        print("event_type", event_type)
        # print("payload", payload)
        # print("metadata_map", metadata_map)
        print("")
        source = MessageSubProcessSourceEnum[event_type.name]
        if self._send_chan._closed:
            logger.debug("Received event after send channel closed. Ignoring.")
            return
        try:
            if payload and EventPayload.RESPONSE in payload:
                pay = payload[EventPayload.RESPONSE]
                if hasattr(pay, "metadata"):
                    if "sub_qa" in pay.metadata:
                        print("sending stream...")
                        await self._send_chan.send(
                            StreamedMessageSubProcess(
                                source=source,
                                metadata_map=metadata_map,
                                event_id=event_id,
                                has_ended=not is_start_event,
                            )
                        )
            else:
                return
        except ClosedResourceError:
            logger.exception(
                "Tried sending SubProcess event %s after channel was closed",
                f"(source={source})",
            )
            return
    
    def start_trace(self, trace_id: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        """No-op."""
    
    def end_trace(
        self,
        trace_id: Optional[str] = None,
        trace_map: Optional[Dict[str, List[str]]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        """No-op."""

async def handle_chat_message(
conversation: schema.Conversation,
user_message: schema.UserMessageCreate,
send_chan: MemoryObjectSendStream,
) -\> None:
async with send_chan:
chat_engine = await get_chat_engine(
ChatCallbackHandler(send_chan), conversation
)
await send_chan.send(
StreamedMessageSubProcess(
event_id=str(uuid4()),
has_ended=True,
source=MessageSubProcessSourceEnum.CONSTRUCTED_QUERY_ENGINE,
)
)
logger.debug("Engine received")
templated_message = f"""
Remember - if I have asked a relevant financial question, use your tools.

{user_message.content}
""".strip()
streaming_chat_response: StreamingAgentChatResponse = (
await chat_engine.astream_chat(templated_message)
)
response_str = ""
async for text in streaming_chat_response.async_response_gen():
response_str += text
if send_chan.\_closed:
logger.debug(
"Received streamed token after send channel closed. Ignoring."
)
return
await send_chan.send(StreamedMessage(content=response_str))

        if response_str.strip() == "":
            await send_chan.send(
                StreamedMessage(
                    content="Sorry, I either wasn't able to understand your question or I don't have an answer for it."
                )
            )


We tried small chat-engine which works correctly. It seems that the problem is with sql pool connection.
